# Why does my Linksys WRT54G have three MAC addresses?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am using a wireless network created from Linksys WRT54G.

1. From 192.168.1.1 (the web for configuring WRT54G), I saw an MAC
   Address:

   ```
   xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:20
   ```
2. From the bottom of the WRT54G device, I saw a different MAC Address:

   ```
   xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:1F
   ```
3. From output of `iwconfig` for `wlan0`, I saw yet another different
   one (is it also a MAC address?):

   ```
   Access Point:   xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:21
   ```

   The whole output of `iwconfig` is

   ```
   $ iwconfig
   eth0      no wireless extensions.

   wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"xxxxx"  
             Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:21   
             Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
             Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
             Power Management:off
             Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-39 dBm  
             Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
             Tx excessive retries:12  Invalid misc:3955   Missed beacon:0

   lo        no wireless extensions.
   ```

All the first three are almost the same, except the last field.

Why does WRT54G have three different MAC addresses? Are they for different components of WRT54G? Thanks.

4. In the output of `ifconfig`, are "HWaddr" for some components of router, or for my computer's network adapters?

   ```
   $ ifconfig
   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:50  
             UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
             RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
             Interrupt:20 Memory:fc600000-fc620000 

   lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
             RX packets:15183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:15183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
             RX bytes:1619156 (1.6 MB)  TX bytes:1619156 (1.6 MB)

   wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:34  
             inet addr:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
             inet6 addr: fe80::226:c6ff:fe3e:3034/64 Scope:Link
             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
             RX packets:2159714 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:1624911 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
             RX bytes:2508182583 (2.5 GB)  TX bytes:240222074 (240.2 MB)
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical consumer router has three different network interfaces:

1. WAN
2. LAN
3. Wireless LAN

Each of these interface has its own MAC address.

Comment: Thanks. I added the output of `ifconfig`. In its output, are "HWaddr" for some components of router, or for my computer's network adapters?

Comment: @Tim, Everything shown is from the router.  If you want to see MAC addresses of your computer(s) from the router, try running `arp -a`

Comment: What do "HWaddr" in the output of `ifconfig` mean? They are different from the three I mentioned at first.

Comment: OK... hold on.  Where are you running `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`, on the router or your computer (I originally assumed the router, but I'm now thinking not)?  Those commands will show the details for the machine they're running on.  The "Access Point" field in the output of `iwconfig` is the MAC of the Access Point/Router the machine is connected to.  And "HWaddr" is the MAC address.

Comment: I ran them on my computer. Whose  MAC address is "HWaddr" for?

Comment: @Tim, `ifconfig` outputs the details of the network interfaces on the machine it is run on.  So if it is run on your computer, the HWaddr is of your computer's network interface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22939/discussion-between-heavyd-and-tim).

Comment: my computer has a wireless adapter and a wired adapter. Are their "HWaddr" called their "Mac addresses"?

Comment: do you mean that the MAC address shown in 192.168.1.1  is for WLAN, while the one on the bottom of router is for LAN? Why is that?

Comment: The MAC displayed near the IP 192.168.1.1 is likely the LAN whereas the one on the bottom is probably the WAN.

Comment: (1) Do you have ways to tell which is which? (2) It is not exactly "The MAC displayed near the IP 192.168.1.1 ". 192.168.1.1  is the IP of the router, and I connect to it on my computer to configure the router.   its webpage  shows a MAC address.

Comment: Really I'm just guessing based on your descriptions there is no standard labeling.  You could use ARP.  Connect to the router admin via WiFi, then run `arp -a` and the WLAN MAC will be with 192.168.1.1. Then disable wireless and connect via wired Ethernet and repeat to get the LAN MAC.

Answer (score 2):

Every network interface has its own MAC-address.
I don't know much about linksys routers but, I'm assuming you just have three interfaces, which isn't unlikely for routers.
These would be:

- Internal interface: You probably have some ethernet port on the back panel. These are just part of a switch, which is then connected to router internally. This internal inerface has to have a MAC-address as well.
- Internet port interface, the port where you connect your cable or DSL Internet connection.
- Wireless interface

Again, I don't really know much about linksys hardware.

Answer (score 1):

1 Base [MAC Address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) + 1 MAC address per interface

Comment: Thanks. What differences are between "base Mac addr" and "Mac addr"?